# How to show entire part of the image without cropping or losing the aspect ratio in Android app using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

I have set up an activity where I can upload a product image. `android:id="@+id/iv_add_update_product"` is used as a button to upload the image and `android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"` is where I want my image to appear. It works fine, except that my image doesn't fit perfectly. I mean part of the images is cropped. What I want is my image to be shown completely without cropping or losing the aspect ratio.

NOTE: The image I added using the XML code shows completely in the imageView `@+id/iv_product_image` without cropping or losing the aspect ratio.
I used the same image in my XML and when I upload.

Following is the part of my XML code. I want to do it for iv_product_image.

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fl_product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/add_product_header_image_height"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image_boat"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_add_update_product"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:padding="@dimen/add_update_product_icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_add_photo" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

AddProductActivity.kt

```
 override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    if (v != null) {
        when (v.id) {

            R.id.iv_add_update_product -> {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    )
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    Constants.showImageChooser(this@AddProductActivity)
                } else {
                  
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        Constants.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE
                    )
                }
            }

            R.id.btn_submit -> {
                if (validateProductDetails()) {

                    uploadProductImage()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Constants.kt

```
    fun showImageChooser(activity: Activity) {
  
    val galleryIntent = Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    )
    activity.startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Comment: The ImageView which source is a color - which does not have dimensions - has a scaleType. The ImageView which source is a vector, does not have a scaleType, adjustViewBounds and has both dimensions set to wrap_content. Are you sure you're adjusting the right view?

Comment: After reading your post, I tried replacing `@color/colorImageViewBackground` with `@drawable/img_boat' and the image fit perfectly in the app. However, my issue is not solved as I use this `imageView` to display the image I upload. So, when I upload the image it doesn't fit perfectly. Note: I am using the same image for both purposes.

Comment: What is your issue exactly? Could you update your question by adding code where you change the imageview, what goes wrong and what you expect?

Comment: I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: Not really, no. You state that it works like you expect when you set `@drawable/img_boat`, but it does not when you change it programmatically? If so, could you add Kotlin or Java as well?

Comment: I meant that the image I set through `xml` code using `@drawable/img_boat` is shown completely, without cropping or losing aspect ratio, when I open the app. However, this imageView is used to show the image I upload when running the app. That is where I have the issue.

Comment: Code added in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233143/discussion-between-michiel-and-codist).

Comment: Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you want proper help, you should ask a proper question. As I already asked: please provide an as small as possible code sample which shows to actual problem, so others can reproduce your problem. If the problem happens inside `uploadProductImage()`, shows us what happens in that function.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. 

I find out the culprit in my code, `.centerCrop()` in the `GlideLoader`. I removed it and added two other lines `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for the `imageView` in the `xml` file. Now I can manipulate it to show the image the way I want. I have also given it a `android:maxHeight="300dp"` to not cover the entire screen with the image.